# Shell script for batch converting video

Tags: bash, filenames

I'm attempting to write a script for use with HandbrakeCli to convert .mkv-files to XBOX 360 compatible mp4-files.

```
#!/bin/bash
for f in "$@"
do
    echo "$f"
    HandbrakeCli -i "$f" -o ~/Movies/Handbrake/"${f%.*}.mp4" --preset "Normal" --mixdown "stereo" --subtitle "1" --width 720 --keep-display-aspect
done
```

The problem is that the destination filename (according to output from HandbrakeCli) includes the full path to the input file. Naturally I'm only interested in the filename without extension since I add .mp4.

I'm not used to shell scripting so help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Also see this discussion of this question on stackoverflow:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/965053/extract-filename-and-extension-in-bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First remove the path:

```
outf=${f##*/}
```

Then change the extension:

```
outf=${outf%.*}.mp4
```

(Not necessarily in that order, of course.)

Answer (score 2):

Since you know the extension of your input file, you can say

```
new=~/Movies/Handbrake/"$(basename "$f" .mkv)".mp4
```